# Swagger UI does not show Params

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I've got a Spring-Application (2.1.0.RELEASE) and added Swagger and Swagger-UI (2.9.2).

I have a `SwaggerConfig` class, that I copied from the [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Then, there is the `App` class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

And there is the actual REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class TweetRating {

    @GetMapping("/{userid}/tweet")
    public static void getTweet(@PathVariable String userid){
        System.out.println("UserID: "+ userid);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public static void isWorking(@RequestParam String id){
        System.out.println("ID: "+ id);
    }
}
```

The Swagger-UI just won't show the params of the methods. Neither the `PathVariable` not the `RequestParam`. Therefore, the "Try it out" function does not make any sense, of course. It looks like this:

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJ2y.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXDRO.png)

Why is that and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply enableUrlTemplating(true)  in you SwaggerConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())  
          .enableUrlTemplating(true)                        
          .build();                                           
    }
```

Also try this one :

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Dexcription of endpoint")
@RequestMapping
public String doSomething(@ApiParam(value = "Description of path vaiable")@PathVariable("/{code}")
```

Comment: Updated answer please take a look

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Yes, somehow. Declaring the variables finally did the job.